# How secure are station clocks (using DCF77)?

Tags: radio, wave, security

In the Netherlands, we have clocks at train stations like on the one on the image below.

[image]

In order to get the time as precise as possible, the clocks read the time from the [DCF77](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DCF77) signal. (As far as I know, for the sake of this question, let's say it is the case.) DCF77 is a longwave time signal from Germany used in mainland Europe.

My question is, how secure are these clocks?

What would happen if I would broadcast a completely other time on the same wavelength near such a clock? Would the time change?

**Disclaimer:** I'm absolutely not planning on doing this. (Otherwise, I would have found out myself.) I'm just curious about how secure these clocks are.

Comment: I read that the second hand makes a full cycle in 57 seconds, rather than 60. Each beat of the second hand is only 0.95 seconds long. THen resyncs every minute something like the 50 or more year old IBM clocks in classrooms which would sync to the master clock with a magnetic latch at 12.

Comment: @Kevin Well, the specification for DCF77 time format is public, so that would be a good place to start looking. My hunch is that there's no security except for the practical issues.

Comment: This is not an EE question. VTC!

Comment: I think that you won't be unnoticed if you build such large scale transmitter.

Comment: The wavelength of a 77 kHz signal is about 4 km. What kind of antenna are you planning to use?

Comment: Even the Wikipedia page is clear enough for an answer.  The DCF77signal has no security or even error checking features.

Comment: @CL As I said in the disclaimer, I'm not planning anything. :)

Comment: @CL.: What kind of antenna do you think the clock uses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DCF77 signal transmits bits by dropping the amplitude of the 77 kHz carrier wave to 15 % of its normal value for a specific amount of time:
[image: amplitude modulated DCF77 signal as a function of time]
<sup>(source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:DCF77_code.svg), CC0)</sup>

If you transmitted your signal so that the receiver sees it at the same amplitude as the original signal, all you could do is to change a 1 bit to a 0 bit, or to make the signal unusable.

But if your signal is strong enough, you would be able to override the original signal completely.

(The DCF77 signal is also [phase modulated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DCF77#Phase_modulation), but almost no receiver actually uses that.)